# How can I pass XML from Delphi to C# without writing to disk?

Tags: c#, delphi, ipc

I have a Delphi application that produces a blob of data that I am currently writing to a file system as xml. This data is then read in by a C# .Net application for further processing.

The issue is that the object graph is large and the resultant xml file is 2 GB+ in size. It takes a relatively long time to write the xml file, and also to read it.

Instead of writing to the file system, how can I transfer the data in RAM where it will be much faster?

I have source code and compilers for both applications. I am using .Net version 4.0 and VS2010  for one application. The other I am using Delphi 5 (I have access to later versions, but I'm unsure if a migration would help).

UPDATE: Thanks for all the suggestions, it's a lot to process. I will post back after further review.

Comment: How about using sockets.

Comment: DELPHI 5 is filled with tons of MEMORY leak issues.. do you have access to Delphi 7 or higher.. or Prism..?

Comment: There are lots of methods out there that can achieve that. I suggest you take a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The one that's the best for you depends a lot on the specifications for your project.

Comment: do you have code samples that you can show.. also in delphi application make sure in the areas where you have loops or while statements, within that section add "Application.ProcessMessages" also make sure you are FreeAndNil(Objects) that you are creating you could also look at Interop

Comment: Interprocess communication is what you're looking for. Another possibility is to save it in a binary format instead of XML, since processing all of the XML will take quite a while and bloat the data.

Comment: Delphi 5 is 32 bit only. You can't access >2GB of memory all at once. You'll have to transmit the file in pieces. How are you generating the XML?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Suggesting the addition of calls to `Application.ProcessMessages` is not helpful. My recommendation would be to find any such calls and remove them. If the process is slow and the UI needs to be kept alive, put the long running code in a background thread as nature intended.

Comment: David I agree if this is coded in C# but If I am not mistaken I think he was asking about the legacy application which is in Delphi 5

Comment: @DJ Delphi 5 can create threads

Comment: I know that.. David I think that you are not familiar with the issues Delphi 5 has..I will let you help / provide the OP with a viable solution.. have a good day

Comment: @DJ Delphi 5 is old sure, but that doesn't mean you have to abandon common sense and start calling Application.ProcessMessages like a VB6 programmer calls DoEvents. And I'm very familiar with Delphi 5 thank you.

Comment: Wouter van Nifterick Ha the reputation tags don't mean a thing you DUFS

Answer (score 6):

Some more suggestions:

[Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)

[Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket)

[RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)

[ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX)

My personal recommendation would be sockets, using [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/index.en.aspx) on the Delphi side and [System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) on the .NET side.

Answer (score 3):

You can integrate both into a single process . That would give you a speed benefit as you don't need any inter process communication.

Three ways to do this:

- load the Delphi code as DLL in a C# process (using PInvoke)
- load the C# code as managed assembly in your Delphi process using [inverse PInvoke](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorConUK2002/Interop1/Win32AndDotNetInterop.htm)
- use [Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/) from RemObjects to do one of the above, and handle the details for you

If you do that using Delphi XE2 or higher, you can have everything in a single 64-bit process and more easily allocate 2GB+ of memory.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to speed this up considerably by compressing (gzip, etc.) the XML stream as you write it to the disk, then decompress on the other end.  Don't be suprised if you get a 10x reduction in size, and therefore I/O.  Sure, you're trading I/O for CPU work, but it's relatively easy work for the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

You could send it as a SOAP message.

Answer (score 0):

best Way, i using it now to trasfer images from c# to delphi at 30fps is:

1- in create a c# COM LIBRARY (exposing GUI elements)

2- register a c# COM LIBRARY with regasm -register -tlb dllname.dll

3- load the type library created in delphi and use c# functions sending ou retriving any data